# can't do postback on .NET page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add some functionality to a page I have inherited, but I am unable to do a postback on the page.  This is how the button appears when I view source :

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentBody$btnUpload" value="Upload" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentBody$btnUpload&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentBody_btnUpload" />
```

And this is how it looks in design mode :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFile_Click" Text="Upload" />
```

Can anybody please help with this, I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out why I can't postback!

Comment: Did you check if you've got any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: What do you mean with "add some functionality to a page I have inherited"? You inherited the page from other page or you got this page from a colleague? Are you using ASP.Net-Ajax?

Comment: How does this inability to do a postback manifest itself? What happens when you try? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Another thing to note is that WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions should only be used if you set the postbackurl which you are not so it might be possible that it's not doing the postback to your page? To test this if you've got a masterpage is put a breakpoint in the masterpage's page_onload and see if it breaks there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So when you click submit nothing happens?

Ensure that it is not because one of the validation controls on the page is returning false.

Comment: If this would be the case then ValidationGroup="????" would be mentioned. Isn't that ?

Comment: Not really, you can do validations without validation groups too. Sometimes, the error message could just be hidden because it has been specified as empty in the error message field of validator control or it is hidden via css/styles.

Comment: Validation controls were the problem...there was one hiding somewhere that a quick scan of the page didn't find

Answer (score 0):

Check your validation control enclosed by container which might be display none. that causes same problem in my case. Just Check all validation control mostly in case where you build single page application or tabbed pages out of which one of tab has validation control.